# run shell command on a cluster using python

Tags: python, shell

I want/am trying to run shell command(Usually file manipulation) on a cluster(a spark cluster 1 master and 3 worker node).

There is passwordless ssh between all the machines in the cluster.

File directories are all same on all cluster Nodes.

Currently I am handling  file manipulation shell command by

```
 #let's say copy or move a file from one dir to other dir
 import os, sys
 os.system('ssh user@Ip_of_worker-1 "cp directory_1/file1.csv directory_2"')
 os.system('ssh user@Ip_of_worker-2 "cp directory_1/file1.csv directory_2"')
 os.system('ssh user@Ip_of_worker-3 "cp directory_1/file1.csv directory_2"')
```

And I am looking for a python package to do that, generally I am trying to avoid system call every time I want to run a shell command(I should get stdout & stderr for each command run on different cluster_Nodes in running python script log.).

And shell command should run in parallel/simultaneously on all target Nodes.

Please guide, if any such package you guys are aware of or have used before.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import thread
import subprocess

# Define a function for the thread
def run_remote(host, delay):
    remote_cmd='cp directory_1/file1.csv directory_2'
    ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no', host, remote_cmd],
                           shell=False,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = ssh.stdout.readlines()

    if result == []:
        error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
        print "ERROR: %s" % error
    else:
        print result


# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( run_remote, ("Ip_of_worker-1", 1, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( run_remote, ("Ip_of_worker-2", 1, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( run_remote, ("Ip_of_worker-3", 1, ) )


except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

Comment: Do u mean thread.start_new_thread( remove_file, ("Ip_of_worker-1", 1, ) ) instead of thread.start_new_thread( run_remote, ("Ip_of_worker-1", 1, ) )

Comment: With this method you can run simultanously ssh connections, also you can use paramiko or fabric as ssh libraries

Comment: Getting:  Unhandled exception in thread started by
sys.excepthook is missing......Seems like I need to use Threading module in place of thread??

Comment: Can I see your script? also host must be user@Ip_of_worker-1 (with user and @). The subprocess.Popen should be the next one: subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no', 'user@Ip_of_worker-1', 'cp directory_1/file1.csv directory_2']

Comment: Also first check in the shell if ssh, -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no, user@Ip_of_worker-1 'cp directory_1/file1.csv directory_2' is working

Comment: Yes, in shell it's working.   ssh user@Ip_of_worker-1 "cp directory_1/file1.csv directory_2" ........And I have just edited your code and provided proper value like real ip,dir...etc

Comment: And is not working? Try removing oStrictHostKeyChecking from the Popen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133539/discussion-between-loneranger-and-lapinkoira).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library implementing ssh protocol, for example paramiko, if you are not happy with system or subprocess. http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/

Hannu

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for pdsh and call this using python.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdsh

Example
http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2014/166/Parallel-Shells

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want Fabric - http://www.fabfile.org/

From their basic example:

```
from fabric.api import run

def host_type():
    run('uname -s')
```

Gets you:

```
$ fab -H localhost,linuxbox host_type
[localhost] run: uname -s
[localhost] out: Darwin
[linuxbox] run: uname -s
[linuxbox] out: Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

[parallel-ssh](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh) is a non-blocking parallel ssh client that can do this:

```
from pssh.pssh2_client import ParallelSSHClient

client = ParallelSSHClient(['host1', 'host2']
output = client.run_command('cp directory_1/file1.csv directory_2')
client.join(output)
```